# OpenAPI 3.0 ref for array

Tags: arrays, json, openapi, redoc

I have recently delved into the OpenAPI specifications and have been making use of `redoc-cli`, however, I have come across a small problem.

I have the following:

```
      "OrderResponse": {
        "allOf": [
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/QuoteOrderResponse",
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "trips": {
                "type": "array",
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/QuoteOrderResponse"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

However, the resulting output is in the form of an object.
[image: trips result]

Hope there are some gurus here that are able to help me to see what is wrong with this. Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid JSON - it' needs `{ }` around the `"$ref": "..."` key/value.

Answer (score 2):

update on this issue, I have found the error, it was a simple mistake which I overlooked.

Basically had to do:

```
        "allOf": [
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/QuoteOrderResponse",
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "trips": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/QuoteOrderResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```